# Firebase Database - change value only by creator?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Is there a way to let only the creator of the room (by uid) change the value of **ready**? Maybe in rules? I've no clue.

```
room
    -L55EIcL2HfaGCKpKN9o
        creatorUid: "GCKpKjFHUccihC0ikxmXjnqO82"
        ready: false
        user
            -L55FCzXGL7IbPyNJXhI 
                uid: "GCKpKjFHUccihC0ikxmXjnqO82"
            -L55GK540811AQl0TDYt
                uid: "KRVpMnjjFHUccihC0C0ikxmXjF"
```

I tried:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "room": {
      "$ready": {
        ".write": "$creatorUid == auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I get the error:

> Line 10: Unknown variable '$creatorUid'.

Creating a room with following JS code:

```
let user = firebase.auth().currentUser
                let room = dbRoomRef.push()
                room.set({
                    creatorUid: user.uid,
                    creatorName: user.displayName,
                    ingame: false,
                    timestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
                })
```

Comment: Please show us the rules that you've tried so far and why it hasn't worked.

Comment: Securing user data is done through Firebase's server-side security rules, as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security. If you're having trouble making them work for your use case, edit your question to include the rules that reproduce where you are stuck.

Comment: Hello  Rosário. Sorry, now I added my rules which doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade):

> Shallower security rules override rules at deeper paths. Child rules
>   can only grant additional privileges to what parent nodes have already
>   declared. They cannot revoke a read or write privilege.

This means that the `".read":true` and `".write":true` will override any other rule you specify under the root node. So you might want to start by removing that `".write":true` line.

The node under the "room" node is the `roomID`, not the ready child. The ready child is under the `roomID`, so you'll have to follow that structure:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    "room": {
      "$roomID": {
        "ready":{
            ".write": "data.parent().child('creatorUid').val() == auth.uid"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that I've used the [`parent()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#parent) method in the rule to access the roomID node, then [`child()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#child) to access the creatorUid under that same node. Then I compare if it's value is equal to the auth.uid.

Comment: Thank that works so far but now I can't create a room anymore. What do I've to do to let authed user create a new room without overwriting me writing rule to the ready node?

Comment: Please post the code you're using to create a new room

Comment: Your rules look good, but only allow modifying the `ready` property. So `ref.child("/room/-L55EIcL2HfaGCKpKN9o/ready").set(true)`. Writing data to higher levels in the JSON will be rejected.